# How to update selenium server stand alone in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, automation, protractor

How to update selenium server stand alone in protractor?
I need to update it to v 2.47.0.Because Firefox version 38 not supporting in v 2.44.0

When I use following comment,
**node node_modules\protractor\bin\webdriver-manager update**

it is saying,
selenium standalone is up to date.
chromedriver is up to date.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the version `webdriver-manager` downloads by altering Protractor's config.json file...

1. Edit Protractor's config file: `node_modules/protractor/config.json`
2. Change the selenium version to whatever you need. eg. `"selenium": "2.47.1",`
3. Run `webdriver-manager update`

You should be good to go.

Comment: Hope for protractor I need to download the following one.
Javascript (Node) 2.46.1 2015-06-15.

There after what should I do?..Can I paste the downloaded .JAR into my node modules-->selenium location. Currently it has 2.44.0

Comment: I updated my answer with a better solution. That said, I don't see a 2.46.1 version available... but perhaps 2.47.1 (the latest) will work for you. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @Brine..This one worked for me.
Small modification.Step:3 We just need to use-webdriver-manager update instead of node_modules/protractor/webdriver-manager update

Comment: @Brine I am having a similar problem which is fixed by your solution however in my project I have in my package.json for 'devDependencies' '"protractor": "~2.1",'. When i do the solution you said to go into the node_modules/protactor/config.json that work but this will only solve it locally. When I check in my package to my git it will still use the older selenium as I can't change what protractors or is there a way to override what protractor is using in my package.json?

Comment: By "check in my package to git", do you mean it's running on CI? I'm not following. Consider asking a new question, as comments aren' the best place for discussion.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to manage versioning through package.json, to ensure that everyone will get same standalone servers.

We just solved this issue in my team by fixing the minor version of protractor to "~2.1.0" in package.json, to make sure we get standalone v2.45.0 when we do `./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --standalone`.

So in your case, try setting protractor to something like "~2.5.0" in package.json, and after you do `npm install` and `webdriver-manager update --standalone` you'll get v2.47.0.

Demo:

[image: updating package.json]

`npm install`

[image: selenium version updated]

[image: getting the right version]

**Note:**

After running `npm install` you will see that the selenium version defined in node_modules/protractor/config.json that [Brine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1818555/brine) mentioned, is updated to the corresponding protractor version.

Comment: Fantastic! Is there a way to override the version specified in the protractor/config.json from the package.json within the project directory?

Answer (score 0):

**You can update selenium-server-standalone jar in two ways** :

1. Update to **latest** version :

> ```
>  webdriver-manager update --standalone
> ```

2.a. Update to **Specific** version **globally** :

Globally means at : **user's AppData** location

```
"C:\Users\pritam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium"
```

> ```
>  webdriver-manager update --versions.standalone "specific_version"
> ```

Example :

> ```
>  webdriver-manager update --versions.standalone 3.0.1
> ```

2.b. Update to **Specific** version for specific **project** :

> ```
>  node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.standalone "specific version"
> ```

Example :

> ```
>  node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.standalone 3.0.1
> ```